# How to use io.dropwizard.lifecycle.Managed with com.mongodb.MongoClient?

Tags: java, mongodb, dropwizard

I am trying to do the following in a Dropwizard app:

```
 public void run(SandmanConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
   MongoClient mongoClient = configuration.getMongoFactory().build(environment);
   environment.lifecycle().manage(mongoClient);
  }
```

This references the MongoFactory's build method:

```
public MongoClient build(Environment environment) {
        // Example conn string: "mongodb://db1.example.net,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=test"
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(getHost(), getPort());
        environment.lifecycle().manage(new Managed() {
            @Override
            public void start() {
            }
            @Override
            public void stop() {
                LOGGER.info("Mongo Client is being shut down...");
                mongoClient.close();
            }
        });
        return mongoClient;
    }
```

How ever when i try to use mongoClient this way I get an error:

```
environment.lifecycle().manage(mongoClient);
Cannot resolve method 'manage(com.mongodb.MongoClient)
```

Comment: you are adding the client twice. Does your MpngoClient class implement the Managed interface? If you add it in the build method, you do not have to add it again. If your client does not implement the interface, you can not add it to the managed lifecycle, which is what is happening in your example. Remove the environment.lifecycle().manage(mongoClient); line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that the best is to create a separate call that implements start and stop for the mongo client.

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import io.dropwizard.lifecycle.Managed;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MongoClientManager implements Managed {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoClientManager.class);
    private final MongoClient client;

    public MongoClientManager(MongoClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("MongoClient is starting up...");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("MongoClient is being shut down...");
        client.close();
    }
}
```

This way I can safely shut down the client when the app is stopping.